# Adler-32 checksum(s) in a PNG file

Tags: png, zlib, checksum

I am currently writing a C program that builds a PNG image from a data file generated by another. The image is a palette type.

Is the Adler-32 checksum calculated on the uncompressed data for...

a)  each compressed block within an IDAT data chunk?

b)  all compressed blocks within an IDAT data chunk?

c)  all compressed blocks spanning all IDAT data chunks?

From the documents at http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950 and rfc1951 (at the same address as previuos) I am of the opinion that it is case 'c' above, allowing one's deflate implementation to chop and change how the data are compressed for each block and disregard how the compressed blocks are split between consecutive IDAT chunks.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There can be only one compressed image data stream in a PNG file, and that is a single zlib stream with a single Adler-32 check at the end that is the Adler-32 of all of the *uncompressed* data (as pre-processed by the filters and interlacing). That zlib stream may or may not be broken up into multiple IDAT chunks. Each IDAT chunk has its own CRC-32, which is the CRC-32 of the chunk type code "IDAT" and the *compressed* data within.

I'm not sure what you mean by "allowing one's deflate implementation to chop and change how the data are compressed for each block". The deflate implementation for a valid PNG file must compress all of the filtered image data as a single zlib stream.

*After* you've compressed it as a single zlib stream, you can break up that stream however you like into a series of IDAT chunks, or as a single IDAT chunk.

Comment: With regards to "allowing one's deflate implementation to chop and change how the data are compressed for each block" is a reference to each block possibly having a different value for the BTYPE.

Comment: Then yes, you can assemble the deflate stream however you like, so long as it is a valid, single deflate stream with one last block at the end. This has no relation to the IDAT chunking.

Comment: "After you've compressed it as a single zlib stream you can break up that stream" Just to clarify: that "after" is rather conceptual. I mean, the implementation does not need to have the full compressed stream in memory to start breaking it in IDAT fragments (and eventually trasmit them), it can be done progressively.

Answer (score 2):

PNG `IDAT` chunks are independent from the compressed blocks. The Adler-32 checksum is part of the zlib compression *only* and has nothing to do with the PNG's overall meta-structure.

From [the PNG Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#C.IDAT):

> There can be multiple IDAT chunks; if so, they must appear consecutively with no other intervening chunks. The compressed datastream is then the concatenation of the contents of all the IDAT chunks. The encoder can divide the compressed datastream into IDAT chunks however it wishes. (Multiple IDAT chunks are allowed so that encoders can work in a fixed amount of memory; typically the chunk size will correspond to the encoder's buffer size.) **It is important to emphasize that IDAT chunk boundaries have no semantic significance and can occur at any point in the compressed datastream.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Yes, the Alder-32 is only concerned with the uncompressed data stream and is independent of the PNG chunks. A PNG file can have >= 1 IDAT chunks that store the compressed image data. The Alder-32 checksum is for the uncompressed image data only. So referring to my question is there just one single Alder-32 checksum for the entire uncompressed image data (option c as suspected) or another?

Comment: @SkyPirate: a small correction to your comment: It's "Adler", not "Alder".